# finisher.co/lab/header in Vue js

Tags: vue.js

Anyone who knows how to use [finisher.co/lab/header](https://finisher.co/lab/header/) in a Vuejs project?

as a beginner I'm having a hard time how to include a [finisher.co/lab/header](https://finisher.co/lab/header/) in my Vuejs project

Comment: You preferably shouldn't do that as a beginner. Stick to Vue-friendly libraries. Using the ones that aren't designed to be used together with modern frameworks brings several problems that require some skills to solve them

Comment: @EstusFlask, what kind of problems do you mean?

Comment: @Tolbxela The same as with jQuery. A lib doesn't take into account that page contents aren't permanent and can be changed by the framework any moment, and there there's a need for a cleanup. This may work fairly well for a thing that's used once per app like this one but the problem is still there

Comment: Yes, you are right. Dynamic libraries changing DOM should be used very carefully with Vue.js or should better not be used at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since [Finisher Header](https://finisher.co/lab/header/) is just a simple library to create animated headers, I don't see any problems using it beside in a Vue.js project.

As long you don't want to have a complete wrapper controlling all properties of the header, just put the generated header next to your Vue app in the project.

See the playground below.

If you like to render the header after the Vue app is mounted, then put the initialization of the header inside the `mounted()` hook

```
mounted() {
  new FinisherHeader({
      ....
   });
}
```

This works also.

**Just don't put the initialization of the header before Vue app.**
It does not work then.

If there will be  any conflicts between libraries, just comment out the header, to check if the problem is really caused by a conflict or it is something else in your Vue app.

The best way to avoid conflicts is to separate the header from the Vue app in the HTML.

```
<body>
    <div class="header finisher-header" style="width: 100%; height: 300px;">
        Logo, navigation, etc.
    </div>
    <div id="app">
        Vue App
    </div>
</body>
```

If you do it this way, the possibility of a conflict between the Vue App and the Header will be very very small.

Playground

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue;

const app = createApp({
  data() { 
    return { time: new Date() }
  }
 }
)
app.mount('#app')

new FinisherHeader({
  "count": 6,
  "size": {
    "min": 1100,
    "max": 1300,
    "pulse": 0
  },
  "speed": {
    "x": {
      "min": 0.1,
      "max": 0.3
    },
    "y": {
      "min": 0.1,
      "max": 0.3
    }
  },
  "colors": {
    "background": "#9138e5",
    "particles": [
      "#6bd6ff",
      "#ffcb57",
      "#ff333d"
    ]
  },
  "blending": "overlay",
  "opacity": {
    "center": 1,
    "edge": 0.1
  },
  "skew": -2,
  "shapes": [
    "c"
  ]
});
```

```html
<body id="app">
  <div class="header finisher-header" style="width: 100%; height: 300px;">
    <h1> Header </h1>
    <h2> Time: {{time.toLocaleTimeString()}} </h2>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://finisher.co/lab/header/assets/finisher-header.es5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```